# Setting CventSessionHeader CVENT API WSDL

Tags: java, wsdl

I am generating Java classes from the CVENT WSDL file using a maven plugin (see the sample below from my POM file).  The code generates successfully.

I then call the code (see below) (the start and end dates passed into the getUpdated call are parameters to my method)

When I run / debug, it connects succesfully, but the getUpdated call fails:

Fault from server: INVALID_CVENT_HEADER_VALUE

In examples online, I can see that I need to set the header on the session - but I don't see any method in V200611Soap that allows me to set it.

Anyone with experience of this, or any sample code?

Thanks in advance.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
    <configuration>
      <wsdlUrls>
        <wsdlUrl>https://api.cvent.com/soap/V200611.ASMX?WSDL</wsdlUrl>
      </wsdlUrls>
      <keep>true</keep>
      <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>






V200611 aV200611 = new V200611();

V200611Soap soap = aV200611.getV200611Soap();

String accountNumber = "xxxxxx";

String userName = "xxxxxx";

String password = "xxxxxx";

LoginResult logingResult = soap.login(accountNumber, userName, password);

CventSessionHeader header = new CventSessionHeader();
header.setCventSessionValue(logingResult.getCventSessionHeader());

GetUpdatedResult getUpdatedResult = soap.getUpdated(CvObjectType.TRAVEL, startDateXMLGregorianCalendar, endDateXmlGregorianCalendar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by changing to use the cxf plugin

Then added the wsdlOption

```
<extendedSoapHeaders>true</extendedSoapHeaders>
```

Which puts the arguments that are implicit (in the wsdl:binding but not wsdl:port), into the generated API classes.